# vue table show data v-for v-if

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

This is my HTML code

```
<table id="showdata">
  <tr>
    <th>Room1</th>
  <th>Room2</th>
    <th>Room3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-if="detail.room === 'Room1'" v-for="detail in roomDetail">
    <td>{{detail.time}}</td>
    <td>{{detail.name}}</td>
    <td>{{detail.status}}</td>
    <td>{{detail.room}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I expected fill data in a table like this :

```
ROOM1                 ROOM2                 ROOM3             
12.00 Anna  Y Room1   09.00 Bob   Y Room2   08.00 Anna N Room3
14.00 Harry N Room1   10.00 Anna  Y Room2                      
                      13.00 Harry N Room2
```

I want to show a new room in the same row. How can I do?

Comment: You've shown what you expect but what do you actually get?

Comment: You'll need a table within a table for a start (though, you could do it without tables at all using grid or flex but that's not the important thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a table within a table

Something like this

```
<table id="showdata">
    <tr>
        <th>Room1</th>
        <th>Room2</th>
        <th>Room3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td v-for="(x, key) in ['Room1', 'Room2', 'Room3']" :key="key" >
            <table>
                <tr v-for="(detail, key) in roomDetail.filter(({ room }) => room === x)" :key="key" >
                    <td>{{ detail.time }}</td>
                    <td>{{ detail.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ detail.status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ detail.room }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You'll probably also want the following CSS

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```